# 近似値の求め方について

Tags: ruby

```
a=2.49
b=1.50
c=2.21
d=1.94
e=2.38

stan=2.00
```

上記のような値があり、a~eの中で最もstan(2.00)に近い値を求めたいのですが調べてもなかなか見つけきれません。調べ方が下手なのかもしれませんが...。
何かアドバイス頂けるとありがたいです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「近似値の求め方」よりも、「リストの中で、ある値に最も近いものを選ぶ」の方が近い気がします

Comment: `min_by()` が適当かと思います。`lst = [a, b, c, d, e]`, `lst.min_by{|x| (x - stan).abs}`

Comment: どちらの方法も成功しました。min_byでやればよかったんですね。そしてlambda関数は初めて知りました。勉強になります。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リストにしてラムダ関数でソートしてみました

```
l = [a, b, c, d, e]
l.sort_by(&lambda{|e| (e-stan).abs})[0] # => 1.94
```