# ハッシュに対するlambda関数について

Tags: ruby

[近似値の求め方について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47974/%E8%BF%91%E4%BC%BC%E5%80%A4%E3%81%AE%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A7%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%97)、回答して頂いたのですが回答のラムダ関数について質問です。

```
a=2.49
b=1.50
c=2.21
d=1.94
e=2.38

stan=2.00

l = [a, b, c, d, e]
l.sort_by(&lambda{|e| (e-stan).abs})[0] # => 1.94
```

これがハッシュの場合はどうなるのでしょうか。
例えば`l = { "m"=>a, "n"=>b, "o"=>c, "p"=>d, "q"=>e }`の場合に、ラムダ関数をしようして、stan(2.00)に最も近いものを取得し、ハッシュ左の"m"や"n"を出力するにはどのように書くのでしょうか。

Comment: `lambda{}.class` の実行結果から分かる様に、ruby の lambda は Proc クラスのインスタンスなのですが、ブロックではなくメソッドとして動作します。ですので、`l.sort_by(&lambda{|(_, e)| (e-stan).abs})[0]` と書くこともできます。

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。どちらの方法でも上手く行きました！どうもありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash#sort_by` は内部的に `Hash#each` を呼び出してます。
`Hash#each` はブロック引数がキーと値の二つになります。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.5.0/method/Hash/i/each.html

実際には要素が2つの配列が渡されます。
今回の場合は、次のように第2引数だけ使えばいいです。

```
l.sort_by(&lambda{|e| (e[1]-stan).abs})[0] # => ["p", 1.94]
```